# WordPress API JSON output not valid with quotes

Tags: json, wordpress, api

I have a custom function that outputs a Json

However the Json Output has always quotes added and is thus unvalid.

```
function my_callback( $data ) {    
  $zz999_ids = do_shortcode('[wpv-view name="json-zz999-ids"]');
  //$result = do_shortcode('[wpv-view name="json-traject-bus" ids="'.$zz999_ids.'"]');

  $result = '[{"bus_id":"BC025","traject_id":"D","traject_show":[["06:00-08:16"]]}]';

  return print_r($result, true);
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', '/traject2/', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'my_callback',
  ) );
} );
```

The result I get is: "[{\"bus_id\":\"BC025\",\"traject_id\":\"D\",\"traject_show\":[[\"06:00-08:16\"]]}]"

I just replaced the $result with a teststring. It is exactly same format that comes through the function.

How to get rid of those outer quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function my_callback( $data ) {    
  $zz999_ids = do_shortcode('[wpv-view name="json-zz999-ids"]');
  //$result = do_shortcode('[wpv-view name="json-traject-bus" ids="'.$zz999_ids.'"]');

  $result = '[{"bus_id":"BC025","traject_id":"D","traject_show":[["06:00-08:16"]]}]';
  $result = json_decode($result);
  return $result;
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', '/traject2/', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'my_callback',
  ) );
} );
```

For you better understanding about **json_decode** please visit [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: when doing this the json feed is empty, just ""

Comment: @ssstofff please visit http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/59e794d8a6ee4b6348dfcfa2d9124ef11be0090f

Comment: it works now! thx, also the string comming from do_shortcode now. the format wasnt correct yet. Thx!